# Getting error :IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence. But actually the list is not empty yet

Tags: python, random, index-error

I'm using random.choice for choosing football player but getting error. It stops after few iterations.

```
class footballist(Person):                            
    def choose(self):                                 
        teams = ['A', 'B']                            
        countA = 0                                    
        countB = 0                                    
        for i in range(0, 22):                        
            team = random.choice(teams)               
            if team == 'A':                           
                countA += 1                           
            else:                                     
                countB += 1                           
            name = random.choice(names)               
            names.remove(name)                        
            print(team, name)                         
            print(countA, countB)                     
            if countA or countB == 11:                
                teams.remove(team)                    
            else:                                     
                pass
```

Comment: It may not be `teams` that's empty, but `names. If `names` is empty, and you try to run `names.remove(name)`, you'll get the error `IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence`. You should put a breakpoint before the loop and step through your code line-by-line while monitoring the contents of your lists. You'll likely find that `names` is empty before that line is run. Or that `teams` is empty before `teams.remove(team)` is run. It just seems like your code needs some simple debugging, which it's not clear that you've even done that.

Comment: `countA or countB == 11` does not do what you seem to think it does.  You want `countA == 11 or countB == 11` probably.

Comment: it's difficult to suggest solutions without a working example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help in preparing this